# kafka Message driven adapter not working

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

Would like to consume messages using kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter.

producing the message in below channels:
headers['topic'] = inMsge_topic,emailMesge_topic

Didn't find good example for the same in the internet either.Please suggest.

Working fine when using
int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter but it requires polling.(want to do without polling)

Below is the configuration using:

```
 <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                                                 auto-startup="true" channel="inputToKafka" message-key="kafka_messageKey">
          <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor" /> 
   </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

   <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
          producer-properties="producerProperties">
          <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
                <int-kafka:producer-configuration
                       broker-list="${kafka.producer.brokerList}" topic="headers['topic']" key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                       value-class-type="com.vo.MessageVO"
                       value-encoder="kafkaEncoder" key-encoder="kafkaKeyEncoder"
                       compression-type="none" />
          </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
   </int-kafka:producer-context>    
   <int:channel id="inputToKafka">
     <int:queue />
   </int:channel>

  <int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
   </int:channel>
 <bean id="kafkaConfiguration" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.ZookeeperConfiguration">
   <constructor-arg ref="zookeeperConnect"/>
```

```
 <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.DefaultConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="kafkaConfiguration"/>
```

```
      <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="adapter"
        channel="inputFromKafka"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        key-decoder="kafkaKeyDecoder"
        payload-decoder="kafkaDecoder"          
        max-fetch="100"
        topics="inMsge_topic"/>

        <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="adapter1"
        channel="inputFromKafka"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        key-decoder="kafkaKeyDecoder"
        payload-decoder="kafkaDecoder"          
        max-fetch="100"
        topics="emailMesge_topic"/>


    <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="localhost:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
    zk-session-timeout="400" zk-sync-time="200" />
```

log output:

20:01:13.130 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=2]@0
20:01:13.131 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=4]@0
20:01:13.131 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=1]@0
20:01:13.131 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=0]@0
20:01:13.131 [pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=3]@1913
20:01:13.134 [pool-11-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=1]@0
20:01:13.134 [pool-11-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=3]@1913
20:01:13.134 [pool-11-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=4]@0
20:01:13.134 [pool-11-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=2]@0
20:01:13.134 [pool-11-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='inMsge_topic', id=0]@0
20:01:13.158 [pool-7-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=1]@0
20:01:13.158 [pool-7-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=3]@334
20:01:13.158 [pool-7-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=0]@0
20:01:13.158 [pool-7-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=4]@0
20:01:13.158 [pool-7-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=2]@0
20:01:13.164 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=1]@0
20:01:13.164 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=4]@0
20:01:13.164 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=0]@0
20:01:13.164 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=3]@334
20:01:13.164 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.i.kafka.core.DefaultConnection - Reading from Partition[topic='emailMesge_topic', id=2]@0

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Spring Integration kafka sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka) - it uses Java configuration instead of XML but it shows both outbound and message-driven adapters.

Comment: Hi Gary,thanks for the suggestion..

kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(received());

@Bean
 public PollableChannel received() {
  return new QueueChannel();
 }

is it going to poll for the message?looking for listener configuration.

Comment: we can use PublishSubscribeChannel/DirectChannel etc as well .is it?

Comment: True. You can. That ` kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(received());` means where messages will be sent after retrieving from the Kafka topic.

Comment: Hi @Artem
Thanks for suggestion.
Trying with Java config example/link mentioned above ,getting error mentione here. (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/75d51a3d1fbe73e0b0ee). Please suggest.

Comment: ` replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0`. No Kafka Broker connected to ZK.

Comment: it is working.My bad,later found that kafka server was down for some reason.

Comment: Hi @Artem,
 
I have tried with @SpringBootApplication/@EnableAutoConfiguration ,it is working in standalone java app with main method(which I also read about in spring-boot document).
But want it to work on the web application,which is not working.
 
Here is my code,Can you please suggest.
 
Kafka producer is working but not the consumer.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/33d582c6582bc29d6a1e

Comment: Looks like you should start a new question and share your web application configuration on the matter. You may just use `consumer` from the separate context which isn't started by the root webapp context.