# Kafka Embedded server with DSL Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using kafka messages driven channel adapter to read messages from kafka topic. It works fine, but when I use embedded Kafka broker for integration test, it not working and doesn't listen to that topic..
Here is the code for Listener

```
    public IntegrationFlow topic1ListenerKafkaFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaMessageListenerContainer(), KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch)
                        .batchMessageConverter(batchMessageConverter)
                        .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                        .outputChannel(inputQueueChannel)).get();
    }



    public AbstractMessageListenerContainer kafkaMessageListenerContainer(){
        AbstractMessageListenerContainer kafkaMessageListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer(consumerFactory(), containerProperties());
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
        return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
    }


    private ContainerProperties containerProperties() {
        ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties("TEST_TOPIC");

        properties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
        properties.setConsumerTaskExecutor(createDefaultTaskExecutor());
        return properties;
    }


    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testConsumerGroup-1");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties);
    }
```

Embedded broker is

```
    public EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker() {
        return new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, false, 1, "TEST_TOPIC")
                .kafkaPorts(9092).brokerProperty("listeners", "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092");
    }
```

here is producer config

```
    public Properties getKafkaProperties() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        return properties;
    }

    public Future<RecordMetadata> sendMessage(String TEST_TOPIC, String message){
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(getKafkaProperties());
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(TEST_TOPIC,"Key", message);
        return  producer.send(producerRecord);
    }
```

when i send  a message it send successfully to topic but **Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter** is not picking up that messages.

I tried a lot but could not find the root cause.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging; if you can't figure it out from that, post the logs someplace like pastebin on a github gist.

Comment: You set Embedded Kafka broker for `TEST_TOPIC`, but looks like your Kafka listener container is configured to listen from `TEST Tpoic`. Is that intentional? Also it is not clear to what topic you send in your `sendMessage(String topicName, String message)`...

Comment: That was typo while posting the code all topic name are same i have updated to TEST_TOPIC.

Comment: OK. Now it's time for you to share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with. Thanks

Comment: I cant send the code its pretty complicated and loading the context using diff XMLs. BUT what i noticed If i use `KafkaTestUtils.getRecords(kafkaConsumer) [Just std props] then Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter picked up message and pass to batchMessageConverter. As per my understanding it should auto pick by **Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter. **.

Comment: Also found similar issue here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552856/kafka-message-driven-adapter-not-working)